# Rx auto-detach behavior, what is it for? how does it work?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

Rx provide the Observable.Create and Observer.Create factory methods, which have auto-detach behavior.

What is it use for? How does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rx will automatically detach the observer the first time you call `observer.OnCompleted()` or `observer.OnError()` or when an unsubscribe occurs.  This guarantees the Rx grammar (the observer will see nothing after it gets a Completed or Error event or after it unsubscribes), even if your custom observable is rogue and attempts to send multiple errors or completions.